# How to handle nullable types in generic class

Tags: kotlin, generics

I want to write a Promise class in kotlin. This class uses a generic type. The type can also be a nullable type. When I call the consumer, the value can be null, if the genereic type is nullable. If not the value must be set to an object. The kotlin compiler shows me following message:
*Smart cast to 'T' is impossible, because 'value' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time*

I understand why this message appears but I am sure, that the value must be correct at this moment. How can I compile this class? I tried to force to access the value with **!!** but then my test with **null** will fail with a NPE.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.Promise.resolve(App.kt:20)
    at test.AppTest.testPromiseNull(AppTest.kt:31)
```

```
class Promise<R> {

    private var resolved = false

    private var value: R? = null

    var then: Consumer<R>? = null

    fun resolve(r: R) = synchronized(this) {
        if (resolved) error("Promise already resolved!")
        value = r
        resolved = true
        then?.accept(value) // Smart cast to 'T' is impossible, because 'value' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time*
    }

    fun then(consumer: Consumer<R>) = synchronized(this) {
        if (then != null) error("Just one consumer is allowed!")
        then = consumer
        val value = value
        if (resolved) {
            consumer.accept(value) // Smart cast to 'T' is impossible, because 'value' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time*
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Test fun testPromise() {
    val promise = Promise<String>()
    var resolved = false
    promise.then {
        assertEquals(it,  "hello" )
        resolved = true
    }
    promise.resolve("hello")
    assert(resolved)
}


@Test fun testPromiseNull() {
    val promise = Promise<String?>()
    var resolved = false
    promise.then {
        assertNull(it)
        resolved = true
    }
    promise.resolve(null)
    assert(resolved)
}
```

**UPDATE**
*I created a little help function*

```
private fun <T> uncheckedCast(t: T?): T {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return t as T
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `resolve` function, you already have the immutable parameter value you can use instead.

```
fun resolve(r: R) = synchronized(this) {
    if (resolved) error("Promise already resolved!")
    value = r
    resolved = true
    then?.accept(r)
}
```

In the other case, since you know more than the compiler, you can do an explicit cast, and suppress the warning.

```
fun then(consumer: Consumer<R>) = synchronized(this) {
    if (then != null) error("Just one consumer is allowed!")
    then = consumer
    if (resolved) {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        consumer.accept(value as R)
    }
}
```